# My Granddaughter got bedbugs in a hostel.

Tags: hostels, bed-bugs

How do I make sure they don't get in my house, when she comes home?  Will the hold of the plane be cold enough to kill them?

Comment: What kind of person downvotes a grandma?

Comment: Surely you're not going to put your granddaughter in the hold ???

Comment: try lifehacks.se

Answer (score 8):

No the baggage compartment is not cold enough to kill bed bugs.

But one would hope she cleans her gear before she flies.  Otherwise the next passengers in her row may find critters left behind.  Other people's bags in the same container could become infested.